# How to have MonthCalendar control display DateTime in PM?

Tags: c#, datetime, monthcalendar

I'm using a MonthCalendar control in a C# App and want to display the DateTime in the afternoon, i.e. PM

I can successfully get it to return DateTime *in the AM* by creating 2-DateTime variables, i.e. DateTime start; and DateTime end;

If I assign these variables like so:

```
start = MonthCalendar.SelectionRange.Start.AddHours(10);
end = MonthCalendar.SelectionRange.End.AddHours(10).AddMinutes(30);
```

then I can set a range from `10:00 AM` to `10:30 AM`. This works fine, but I also need to write back to a DB times in PM.

How can I use the syntax above to display a `DateTime` in the afternoon, like 1:00 PM to 1:30 PM?

I noticed that the calendar control has a `TimeOfDay` feature, but after Googling this as well as searching under `MonthCalendar.SelectionRange.Start.AddHours`, I'm not able to find anything on this. Searched SOF as well, but did not come up with any answer.

Comment: Just add 12 hours. 1 PM `.AddHours(13)`

Comment: Hello Jasen. The adage that the best solution is usually the simplest shines through here. I hadn't remembered that past noon (12), the time would be 13. Easy! Now my scheduler can do the following.                start = MonthCalendar.SelectionRange.Start.AddHours(13);
end = MonthCalendar.SelectionRange.End.AddHours(13).AddMinutes(30); Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to clear a few things;

- You *can't* have a `DateTime` instance like `1:00 PM` or `1:30 PM`. A `Datetime` instance does not have *any* implicit format. It just have date and time values. Formatting concept *only* applies when you get their *textual* (string) representations. That's why you can have string variable for those.
- Saving your `DateTime` values as a string into your database is *usually* a bad idea. Generally speaking, you should save your `DateTime` values instead of strings into your database and generate their string representation when you show them in UI for example.

> How to get those formats based on your DateTime values?

Simple. First, you add `13` and `13,5` (equal to 13 hours and 30 minutes) hours to your `Start` and `End` and use [`.ToString()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tostring) with `h:mm tt` custom format as a first parameter and a culture that uses `AM` and `PM` in [`AMDesignator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.amdesignator) and [`PMDesignator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.pmdesignator) and has [`GregorianCalendar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar) as [`Calendar` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.calendar) like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture) as a second parameter.

```
string startStr = MonthCalendar.SelectionRange.Start.AddHours(13)
                               .ToString("h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string endStr = MonthCalendar.SelectionRange.End.AddHours(13,5)
                               .ToString("h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now you have `1:00 PM`  amd `1:30 PM` as a string variables.

Comment: Hello Soner and thanks for your input. Actually, I'm not working with strings but as stated above I declared 2- DateTime variables, for writing back to a MS SQL DB with a smalldatetime data type. What I'm doing is programmatically setting the start and end times for a scheduler control on my form. Your example (albeit with strings) actually answered my question, although Jasen's answer was more to the point. Since I needed to show some dates and times in the PM, setting the start and end with the value of (13) allowed my scheduler to display the time as I needed.